# How do i decide edges of a general polygon?

Tags: geometry

I want to retrieve **all the edges** of a general polygon, which is described by some 2 dimensional vertexes.

I thought a method to getting all possible combinations and testing if it is intersecting with others at none-vertex point.

But there was a problem, if the polygon is **concave**, we cannot test whether it is the non-edge combination.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Your problem is underdetermined. With no concavity assumptions, there is generally more than one non-self-intersecting polygon with a specified vertex set. Otherwise, the geometric Traveling Salesman Problem would be trivial to solve rather than NP-hard.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, if all you want is *a* polygon through the points rather than *the* polygon through the points, thinking about it as a Traveling Salesman Problem is a decent approach. Use a nearest neighbor heuristic followed by 2-opt to remove edge crossings and the result will be a fairly reasonable polygon passing through your points.

Comment: @John Coleman Okay. So I dont want self-crossing polygon actually, if I apply traveling salesman problem, what value sould i give to weight?

Comment: You spoke of coordinates, so I would just use the distance formula to calculate standard Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try christofides algorithm if your distance satisfy triangle inequation. In tsp it has guarantee of 2/3 of shortest path but it's very difficult problem.